# Caching the webpage in webview offline throws ERR_CACHE_MISS only in some websites

Tags: android, caching, webview

Android cache in webview throws **ERR_CACHE_MISS** for **some website**(my website), even after inserting proper permission as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

in manifest.xml

But for **some website**(https://stackoverflow.com) it doesn't throw anything and working as excepted when i use below code

```
WebView webView;
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
ProgressBar progressBar;
String appCachePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            progressBar.setProgress(100);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(progressBar.getProgress()==100){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });


    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    try {
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null || !connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
        {
            Log.i("err","CACHE OR NETWROK");
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
            webView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("err","CONNECTED");
            appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
            webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
            webView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("err","ERROR"+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I have seen Amazon, Flipkart, Instagram, Facebook android apps cached for offline view perfectly (the post we leave the app will be retrieved when reopen our app while being offline).

I think **OkHTTPClient and Retrofit** offline caching is used for json response and doesnt suit in webpage rendering in webview? Anyother way to cache website in webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you are trying to load should have basic Html and meta tags on the top of the page.In the index file.